# É possível fazer um INSERT INTO SELECT + outros valores fora do SELECT?

Tags: sql

Preciso inserir numa tabela `ACCESS` alguns valores de outra tabela mais o horário e o usuário que fez o registro.

Sei que para pegar os dados da outra tabela é só fazer algo como:

```
INSERT INTO TABELA(ID, NOME, ENDERECO)
SELECT ID, NOME, ENDERECO FROM MEUBANCO2..MINHATABELA
WHERE ..
```

Como faço para também inserir os dados de hora e usuário no mesmo comando `INSERT` INTO, além do `SELECT` (que já está pegando alguns dados de outra tabela)?

Comment: você não pode sisplesmente adicionar um GETDATE()?

INSERT INTO TABELA(ID, NOME, ENDERECO, DATA)
SELECT ID, NOME, ENDERECO, GETDATE() AS 'DATA' FROM...

Comment: Usuário é uma tabela ou o usuário do sistema? Você quer inserir a hora da ação?

Comment: Qual banco de dados?

Comment: Obrigado, @LeandroAngelo!

Comment: É um banco de dados Access, @David. Obrigado! Abs!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode utilizar valores estáticos. Assumindo, como exemplo, que o usuário tem ID 1024:

```
INSERT INTO TABELA (ID, NOME, ENDERECO, USUARIO, DATAHORA)
SELECT      A.ID, 
            A.NOME, 
            A.ENDERECO, 
            1024, 
            Now()
FROM        MEUBANCO2..MINHATABELA A
```

Comment: Obrigado, @OnoSendai !

Comment: @Leandro Não por isso - é sempre um prazer ajudar. =)

Answer (score 4):

Você pode criar os comandos a serem executados:

```
SELECT
    'INSERT INTO ACCESSO (user, hora, url) VALUES ('||U.nome||','||P.hora||','||P.url||');'
FROM
    usuario U
    LEFT JOIN pagina P ON P.user_id = U.user_id
```

Comment: Obrigado, @Guilherme Lautert !